# JOIN XML Documents on Value using LINQ

Tags: xml, linq, join

I need to join two XML documents using LINQ and I'm not sure where to start. I need to join Document 1 and Document 2 on the values of the EmailAddress nodes and create a final output document that contains the value of the status field from Document 2.

Can anyone help?

Document 1

[image]

Document 2

[image]

Final Document

[image]

Comment: Posting your XML as text would've been nice. Images force people to waste time reconstructing code/data in an attempt to help.

Comment: Sorry about that. I tried to post the xml but the editor wouldn't take it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to create a dictionary to map the emails to their status values. Next, select all the email address elements from the first document and set their attributes based on the dictionary.

```
var dict = secondDoc.Descendants("EmailAddress")
                    .ToDictionary(e => e.Value, e => e.Attribute("status").Value);

var emails = firstDoc.Descendants()
                     .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("EmailAddress") 
                       && Char.IsDigit(e.Name.LocalName[e.Name.LocalName.Length - 1]));

foreach (var email in emails)
{
    string attribute;
    if (dict.TryGetValue(email.Value, out attribute))
    {
        email.SetAttributeValue("status", attribute);
    }
}
```

This approach will directly update `firstDoc`; it doesn't create a new `XElement` or `XDocument`. I added the `Char.IsDigit` check to avoid incorrectly matching an `EmailAddress` field that doesn't end with a number, should one exist. If you're certain that will never be the case then you can remove that check from the query.

Comment: @user135498 great :) I made a slight update to the `IsDigit` check to access the last character via the string index and length since `Last` will iterate over the entire string.